# Solaris11: is possible to create an encrypted root and unlock it via usb?

Tags: solaris, encryption, zfs

On Linux is possible: with luks+ext4 or luks+btrfs there are a lot of how-to's on web.
Is also possible [using ZFS](https://www.medo64.com/2020/07/encrypted-zfs-root-on-ubuntu-server-20-04-via-usb-unlock/).

On Solaris 11 is possible something like this?
Using a passphrase on boot is ok only in interactive mode, with an headless pc without a "remote control" like ILO4 or similar is not nice

Comment: And what is the sense to have encrypted filesystem which is decrypted by USB or other device and this device is permanently attached to the machine?

Comment: Simple: I stay near the machine. When I go to vacation I can take the usb key.

Comment: Don't put secrets on your root filesystem.  That's for the OS - and there's nothing secret about the OS that needs to be encrypted.  Encrypting the root filesystem is a solution in search of a problem to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still open to a solution the actually answer is NO.